# Cell editing validated when finished

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying change the colour of a cell based on a set of rules. Once the person has fixed the cell it should go back to black and white. But it appears to be firing when im inserting on the first occasion of inserting data I want this to only fire if the user has changed the value of the cell.

What would the correct method be for that or do all I have is tab and enter key check and then proceed with the code below I had to remove some field names so that it doesn't show our structure below.

Or do I need a dirty state tracker for the cell.

```
private void dgUpdatesPrices_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{

        if (_value== value)
        {
            decimal _spsPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(dgUpdatesPrices.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["NewPrice"].Value);
            decimal _spePrice = Convert.ToDecimal(dgUpdatesPrices.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["NewPriceEuro"].Value);


            checkSPEThreasholds();
            checkSPSThreasholds();
        }
        if(value== value)
        {
            decimal _sterling = Convert.ToDecimal(dgUpdatesPrices.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Sterling"].Value);
            decimal _euro = Convert.ToDecimal(dgUpdatesPrices.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["NewSterling"].Value);

            setupEuroPercentageHightlight();
            setupSterlingPcentageHighlight();

        }
```

**Edit 2**

As suggested I used the event below but how Do i tell it go to a specific column as I do not want all the columns value just specific one on that row. I dont want to use index as that can change I want to use column name

```
private void dgUpdatesPrices_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
        MessageBox.Show(dgUpdatesPrices[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());

}
```

**Edit 3**
To Clarify what i mean if the user changes the new sps price to 34 which matches the SPS price it should remove the formatting of the red of that new sps price cell.

Basically if the price is 20% higher or lower than the sps price the formatting should disapear.
[image]

Comment: I would just go with a flag `IsDataLoaded` or something like that

Comment: always comes back to good old boolean lol

Comment: @EpicKip is that the right event do or is their like a leave cell event.

Comment: `CellEndEdit` might do what you want :)

Comment: @EpicKip that worked a treat but see my second edit please.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean. `e.ColumnIndex` will not 'change' or do you mean to save the index to access it later? Maybe better to save the value then

Comment: @EpicKip no i just mean how do i reference by column name just instead of index. As obv this will fire for every column that is edited

Comment: See my answer, that way you can check on columns by name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To only make this event do anything for specific columns by name (see OP's edit) you can filter on columns like this:

```
if( e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView.Columns["ColumnName"].Index )
    //do stuff
```

**Response to OP edit 3:**

```
if(e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView.Columns["ColumnName"].Index)
{
    var column1Index = dataGridView1.Columns[ "ColumnNameA" ].Index;
    var column2Index = dataGridView1.Columns[ "ColumnNameB" ].Index;

    if(dataGridView[column1Index, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString() == dataGridView[column2Index, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString())
    {
        //They match, remove color
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help i attached screen shot in third edit to show what i meant in detail.

Comment: can you have a look at the third edit their please many thanks.